# AngularJS store embedded objects ID only

Tags: angularjs, nested, json

I've been stuck on something for a bit and maybe I've been searching using the wrong keywords, so haven't found other similar threads.

I'm building an app with angularjs as the front end, REST backends with a simple model.

```
Subtrack.java
  Private String subtrackname

Track.java
  Private String trackname
  Private Subtrack subtrack

Presentation.java
  Private String title
  Private String presenter
  Private Track track
```

All the REST interfaces are defined (built them using JBoss Forge from the above POJOs. I also scaffolded the Angular with Forge) but I can't seem to figure out the Angular form for the creation of a new Presentation where I associate the Track to the presentation.

I have a list of Tracks defined (that could have a subtrack that I put into a list in the new Presentation controller ...

```
$scope.sessionTracksSelectionList = TrackResource.queryAll(function() {});
$scope.sessionSubtracksSelectionList = {};

if ($scope.presentation.sessiontrack != null) {
    $scope.sessionSubtracksSelectionList = $scope.presentation.sessiontrack.subtracks;
}
```

Then my new presentation form looks like this.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': PresentationForm.sessiontrack.$invalid}">
    <label for="sessiontrack" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sessiontrack</label>
    <div id="sessiontrackControls" class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="sessiontrack" name="sessiontrack" class="form-control" ng-model="presentation.sessiontrack" ng-options="s.trackname for s in sessionTracksSelectionList track by s.id">
            <option value="">Choose a session track</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': PresentationForm.sessionsubtrack.$invalid}">
    <label for="sessionsubtrack" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sessionsubtrack</label>
    <div id="sessionsubtrackControls" class="col-sm-10">
        <select id="sessionsubtrack" name="sessionsubtrack" class="form-control" ng-model="presentation.sessionsubtrack" ng-options="s.subtrackname for s in sessionSubtracksSelectionList track by s.id">
            <option value="">Choose a session subtrack</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this seems to work in terms of passing the correct info in the presentation object:

```
{
  room: {id: 9, version: 0, roomname: "santa maria 1"}
  sessionday: 3
  sessionsubtrack: {id: 3, version: 0, subtrackname: "cloud"}
  sessiontrack: {id: 4, version: 0, trackname: "ps", subtracks: [{id: 3, version: 0, subtrackname: "cloud"}, {id: 1, version: 0, subtrackname: "mw"}, {id: 2, version: 0, subtrackname: "inf"}]}
  title: "p3"
}
```

However, it's passing in the entire Track object rather then just the ID, so I'm getting a "value too long error for column Track" as it's only allowing a max of 255 characters and I don't want to increase the size as I don't want to be duplicating all this content in the DB.

So, is there a way for me to only store the ID of the Track that I can then retrieve when I request the presentation?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ngOptions` format so that it writes track id in the model:

```
<select id="sessiontrack" name="sessiontrack" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="presentation.sessiontrack" 
        ng-options="s.id as s.trackname for s in sessionTracksSelectionList track by s.id">
    <option value="">Choose a session track</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work for me for a few reasons: 
- adding s.id as s.trackname, I don't get any options in the select
- also, doing that with Track causes a problem given that I load Subtrack as a child of Track... as such, if that's only an ID, then I can't load the subtracks
- Lastly, I tried it with another field "Room" figuring it was simpler, but when I tried to save that, it failed as there is no constructor for Room with just an ID...

Any other suggestions?